# Role based access in asp.net mvc 3

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, form-authentication

How can i assign role to a user in asp.net mvc3 application ?

i tried doing following

```
   public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (model.user_id == "admin" && model.password == "admin")
            {
                 FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(
                                                    1,
                                                    "admin",
                                                    DateTime.Now,
                                                    DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30),
                                                    false,
                                                    "admin",
                                                    FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath);


                return JavaScript("window.location.replace('/Home/');");
            }

            else
            {
                return Content("Invalid User Id or Password.");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return View(model);
        }
    }
```

Now when i try to get the user role in any views, it never gives me the role as admin. How do i assign role after login ?

Comment: You're doing some very strange things. Why are you not returning Views? Why are you not returning your invalid model? Also, it seems you don't have Forms Authentication set up properly, since you're comparing strings in your code instead of the database.

Comment: @Trickery : it is just for test. i will be retrieving those values from database only.

Comment: Well, this is not how Forms Authentication works. I suggest you follow [this tutorial](http://mvcmusicstore.codeplex.com/). It will show you how to correctly work with MVC and Authentication.

Comment: I am using MySql database.

Comment: So what? Download the .NET MySql provider and read it's documentation. You have no reason to manually handle the authorization cookie.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to access user roles on the view? You should not do that and if there are any specific needs, after fetching the roles from the database store the roles in a model, so that you can read the roles in the view via model property.

If you don't want to change the model then you can also add the property to ViewBag. For eg ViewBag.UserRoles = "admin";

One more thing that I notice is that you are also not creating the principal object and assigning it to the HttpContext.User so that you can perform your authorization based on that.